# The old question of goodness of fit - in R, with 2 datasets and weighted

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, fitting

A common problem I face is to have people asking whether a certain model with a set of parameters fit a dataset sufficiently enough. The problem, of course, is defining sufficiently enough. Recently I come across such a problem that is somehow more complicated than usual.

My data is composed of temporal information about two variables (A and B). We made replicated measures of A and B at different time points. The different variables are measuring things in very different scales. Different time point can have very different variances in the measured values.

At the same time I have a model that can described the process that generate variable A and B. In the simplest scenario, the model outputs a deterministic value for the variables at each time point. How can I test if the model is fitting the data correctly, taking into account in one value the two variables, with very different scales, and the different estimated errors in the measurements?

My initial thoughts went to compute the standard score of each value and test if this distributed as normal distribution. Is this correct? Even if so, this does not test the possibility that residuals are biased...

To further complicate, in the complete scenario my model is a stochastic simulation. This means that for a given set of parameters I have many possible outcomes. I run the model several times and use the mean as if it was a deterministic model, but is there a better way?